# readonly hierarchical model in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos

In my Objective-C application, I have a hierarchy of subclasses of `NSObject` which constitute a model. These objects have no functionality on their own, i.e. they only have properties and their sole purpose is to hold data. Furthermore I have a single controller that manages instances of this hierarchy (tree).

Only that controller shall be allowed to make changes to the tree (e.g. the properties of the objects in the tree). Other parts of the program shall have read-only access to the (whole) tree.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this type of access management?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic case of [friend classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friend_class). While ObjC doesn't have language support for friend classes, they are not difficult to create.

First, the public interface to your model should declare the properties `readonly`. That part should be obvious.

Then internally to the model, you make your properties readwrite as needed in a class extension. (This should also be pretty obvious if you're used to ObjC; if it's not obvious, I'll update the answer.)

Now the rest of the story. Create a "Friend" category (or "Writer" or "Protected" or whatever name is meaningful to you).

```
@interface ModelObject (Friend)
- (void)setSomeProperty:(id)someProperty;
@end
```

This just tells anyone who imports this category that `setSomeProperty:` exists. Now your control will import this file (`ModelObject+Friend.h`) and will be able to set properties. Everyone else imports `ModelObject.h` and the property looks readonly.

This works for anything you need access to, not just properties of course. I often create immutable classes, and then make a "friend-only" `initWithX:andY:andZ:` method.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! It technically works, I see it. But it essentially also means multiplying the model definition code by a factor of three. I was seeking for a more elegant solution (sth. like a @deep-readonly qualifier in the controller definition would be nice. :-)) I wonder if anyone comes up with a more elegant solution.

Comment: On a second thought, this also is not exactly what I am trying to achieve. The other classes should have readonly access to the tree managed by the controller. However, they should be free to create private copies of the model-objects in the tree or to create their own instances of model-objects, as long as they do not modify the objects in the managed tree of the controller. I feel the controller shall be responsible to take protective measures. The model is stupid. This somehow should be reflected in the code.

Comment: I'm not sure how to reflect "stupid" in the code. If your goal is to have mutable and immutable data objects, you can have immutable objects with mutable subclasses, using interfaces like `copy` and `immutableCopy` to manage them (like NSString and NSMutableString). There is no equivalent in ObjC to C++'s "const" however. You cannot return a mutable object with a qualifier that the caller can't mess with it. You can only achieve this with copies. In most cases I find that these concerns suggest an over-complicated model hierarchy, however. Complex models are best managed with Core Data.

Comment: Exactly, the model hierarchy is complex. But I don't want to use CoreData, because I do neither want a persistent store nor undo/redo style behavior. This is a deliberate choice. Now everything would be easy if only one could teach a model-object to know who wants to modify it. I now understand that there is no such mechanism. From your ideas I guess I could give the controller a private and a public tree where the public one is an immutable copy of the private one and is held in sync. Any ideas how to best sync the trees automatically without rebuilding the whole tree upon minor changes?

Comment: Ok, I see, this wouldn't work, because the public tree then would be immutable as a whole. This is all too complicated. What I want sounds so simple. Like an mmap where the model is stored into and the controller has readwrite access and the rest readonly. Then access would be managed by the os. No mechanism my process does this itself? A protected NSZone would be fine. Doesn't exist either... Any ideas?

Comment: Note that Core Data does not require persistent storage. It is perfectly fine and appropriate for in-memory use. Nor does it imply undo/redo. But what you've described doesn't sound that simple. You seem to be saying you want one instance of the tree to be modifiable by some specific other object, but another instance of the tree to be modified by some other specific object (i.e. "make private copies of the model objects"). I'm having trouble envisioning how to check this at compile time in any language. At run-time, it's unclear how it gives much benefit, even if you can implement it.

Comment: Is what you're describing something you could explain in C++ or Java (or even in Haskell or Prolog?) Maybe you could explain the problem more. It sounds somewhat over-complicated. I often find that people over-think data privacy, and that simple conventions often work better than complicated language features.

Comment: @ilmiacs, Can you please explain your requirement with a suitable example?

Comment: @ABC Thank you for reminding me about this question. I have thought about it quite some time and I think there is no easy solution for what I want to accomplish in any other language I speak (C/C++, Python, Lua), too. But the answer given here is correct, considering my question as I have formulated it originally, so I accept it. Possibly I'll start a new question with what I have in mind when I am ready.